# Is it unhealthy to steam my eyes in order to cure Blepharitis?

Tags: blepharitis, steam

In order to treat my Blepharitis, I put a towel over my head and allow steam from a bowl of water to clear the sebaceous glands between my eye lashes, which glands deliver oil to the surface of the eye.

The surface of the eye needs not only moisture, but a small amount of oil in order to form a film across the eyeball. If the oil is not properly delivered, the water in the eye forms a droplet and dribbles out, causing, paradoxically, not only a leaking eye but a dry eye.

My question is, am I damaging my eye by steaming it ?

See my video on Youtube describing Blepharitis and describing the treatment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbJyTR_6gS8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one can answer your question whether you are "damaging your eye by steaming it" because it depends on your methods whether it's harming the eyeball.

Your eye does need moisture, which is the purpose of the oil glands.  If your [blepharitis](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/diseases/blepharitis-treatment) involves clogged oil glands, then they're not putting out the oil that they should.  Therefore using [warm compresses](https://www.aoa.org/patients-and-public/eye-and-vision-problems/glossary-of-eye-and-vision-conditions/blepharitis) to help clear those glands should do the opposite of stopping the oil - it should allow it to come out normally.

But again, regarding STEAM, I cannot say whether your particular method is safe. Make sure you only use a method from a reputable source, and replicate it accurately!

There is more to blepharitis than just oil glands.  Ask your doctor their recommended treatment plan.